# Update the values of a list with their absolute values

Tags: list, function, scala, functional-programming, listbuffer

Newbie to scala.

I am trying to make this code to work for a few hours now . It is intended to update the List[Int](list of integers) with absolute values of the integers.
Took a long time to figure out that List is immutable, so found that ListBuffer can be the saviour, but eventually in returning it back into the List form is seeing some issue i guess.

```
def f (arr:List[Int]) : List[Int] =
{
  val list = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]();
  val len = arr.length;
  for ( i <- 0 to len)
  {
    if(arr(i) < 0)
    {

      list.append((-1)*arr(i)) ;
    }
    else
    {
      list.append(arr(i));
    }
  }

  return list.toList;

}
```

which is giving this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:52)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
at Solution$.f(Solution.scala:7)
at Solution$delayedInit$body.apply(Solution.scala:23)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:7...
```

Not getting what's wrong here.

Comment: `val res = list map math.abs` or `val res = for {i <- list} yield math.abs(i)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to use Scala functions like @senia suggested in comments. For example:

```
val res = list map math.abs
```

But if you want to fix your code just replace `to` with `until`. You are getting off by one error:

```
def f (arr:List[Int]) : List[Int] =
{
val list = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]();
val len = arr.length;
for ( i <- 0 until len)
{
    if(arr(i) < 0)
    {

        list.append((-1)*arr(i)) ;
    }
    else
    {
        list.append(arr(i));
    }
}

return list.toList;

}
```

Here is the difference between `until` and `to`:

```
1 to 3
// Range(1, 2, 3)

1 until 3
// Range(1, 2)
```

You can also remove `return`, `;` and even braces `{` used with `if/else`.

Comment: `List#apply` cost is `O(N)`, so the complexity of your method is `O(N^2)`. At least replace `for ( i <- 0 until len)` with `for ( e <- arr)`

Comment: @senia good point. I'm not trying to write it in a better way, just fixing it to work so that user1043981 would see what the problem was. He was soooo close :). Not that it's the best implementation at all.

Comment: Thanks @senia for multiple answers and insight about the complexity.Can you give some pointers for complexity thing in scala.

Comment: @harshit: see [Performance Characteristics of Scala Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yet another version using a `for` comprehension that avoids indexing,

```
def f (arr:List[Int]) : List[Int] =
{
  val list = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]();

  for {
    a <- arr
    sign = if (a < 0) -1 else 1
  } list.append(sign * a)

  return list.toList;
}
```

As mentioned above, the `return` may be omitted.

Comment: Why not `def f (arr: List[Int]) = for {a <- arr; sign = if (a < 0) -1 else 1} yield sign * a`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using case statements for more neat syntax :

```
def f(arr:List[Int]):List[Int] = {
val list = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]()
arr.foreach{
    x =>
        x match {
        case _ if (x <0) => list+= (x*(-1))
        case _ => list +=x
    }
}
list.toList
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were trying to solve the challenge from [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fp-update-list). Probably you may want to use more functional approach with recursion and immutable List.

```
def f(arr: List[Int]): List[Int] = arr match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case x :: rest => java.lang.Math.abs(x) :: f(rest)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beginner friendly: this is how I wrote it

```
def f(arr: List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
var list = new scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]();
// var len = arr.length;

for(i <-0 until arr.length) {
    list.append( math.abs(arr(i)));
}

return list.toList; }
```

I haven't done any time complexity analysis but it's the most straightforward for beginners to understand. Also, it passes all the tests on hackerrank

Comment: Very poor Scala style: 1) use of mutable `var` 2) `var` not needed because the chosen collection is already mutable 3) use of unneeded `;` 4) use of unneeded `return`

Answer (score 0):

```
def f (arr: List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
 arr.map {
     case i if 0 > i => i * -1
     case i => i
 }
}
```