# How to convert each integers to its absolute value in Scala lists?

Tags: scala

I am trying to convert each list integer to its absolute value using the following Scala statement, I am getting an invalid type match error:

```
def f(arr:List[Int]):List[Int] = arr.map((x: Int) => if(x<0) -1*x)





Solution.scala:2: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[AnyVal]
 required: List[Int]
def f(arr:List[Int]):List[Int] = arr.map((x: Int) => if(x<0) -1*x)
                                        ^
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace elements in List by condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51001759/replace-elements-in-list-by-condition)

Comment: Keep in mind that for the case of `Int.MinValue`, there's no `Int` representation for its absolute value

Comment: Alternative duplicate candidate: [Update the values of a list with their absolute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219993/update-the-values-of-a-list-with-their-absolute-values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on doing it with an `if-else`, then you need both parts of the `if-else` expression:

```
def f(arr:List[Int]):List[Int] = arr.map((x: Int) => if(x < 0) -x else x)
```

It would be easier with `abs`, though:

```
arr.map(_.abs)
```